# Packaging a jar with preconfigured command line arguments

Tags: java, deployment, jar

I am wondering if there's a way to create a jar that includes some command line arguments in it, the arguments that are usually passed in the command line when one tries to start up the jar (these parameters are then passed on to the main function). Basically instead of starting my app with

```
java -jar myapp.jar "arg1" "arg2", I want to start my app with 
java -jar myapp.jar
```

and have "arg1" and "arg2" passed to the main function.

The reason behind this is that I want to deploy this to different environments, and I want my jar to contain different parameters according to the environment it's being deployed at.

Maybe there's another way to achieve similar results ??

Cheers.

PS: Looking for a maven solution.

Edit: I'll add a complete example to make this a bit more clear:

Let's say I have 2 environments: "Production" and "Test". I want to run the jar in the same way no matter in what environment I deploy it. So I always want to run it with:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

But! In order for my 2 environments to run ok, I need the Production environment jar to start it's main method with an argument "prod" and I need the Test environment jar to start it's main method with an argument "test".

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem, in your `main()` you could define a simple logic to handle the case where you do not specify any input parameter; the logic could retrieve the desired values according to the correct platform/env.

As an example:

```
public class Test01 
{
    public static void main(String... aaa) 
    {   
        // Check input
        if(aaa.length == 0) {
            /* Insert logic to retrieve the value you want, depending on the platform/environment.
             * A trivial example could be: */
            aaa = new String[2];
            aaa[0] = "First value";
            aaa[1] = "Second value";
        }

        // Processing, e.g. print the 2 input values 
        System.out.println(aaa[0] + ", " + aaa[1]);
    }
}
```

Fyi, I created a runnable `jar` using eclipse, and start the application by either

```
java -jar Test01.jar
```

or

```
java -jar Test01.jar arg1 arg2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change main(String[] args) to get values from env var if they are not present in the passed arguments.

```
String user;
String password;
if(args.length < 2)
{
    user = System.getenv("appUser");
    password = System.getenv("appPassword");
} else {
    user = args[0];
    password = args[1];
}
```

You can also create another class with a main function that will call the real one.

```
public class CallerMyApp{

public void main(String[] args) {

    String[] realArgs = {System.getenv("appUser"), System.getenv("appPassword")};
    MyApp.main(realArgs);
}

}
```

Then to execute its something like

```
java -cp myapp.jar CallerMyApp
```